# Where is IRemoteControlService.h

Tags: android, android-source

*ATVAudioPolicyManager.cpp* casually refers to [this header](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/device/asus/fugu/libaudio/ATVAudioPolicyManager.cpp#30), but it's nowhere in AOSP.

Is there any way I can get this header (and hopefully also the associated library/source files)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have searched, indeed ***IRemoteControlService.h*** doesn't seem to be anywhere, but also, it is surrounded by ***`REMOTE_CONTROL_INTERFACE`*** which I haven't seen defined anywhere, hence no product would actually try to include it.

Do you have an actual error when compiling *ASUS*'s ***fugu*** device or is that out of curiosity? Could be legacy code no longer maintained.

It is not released in AOSP, it could be part of proprietary sources/libraries/binaries.

Comment: It most definitely is compiled into fugu factory images, based on the logs. I think this might get added with GATVapps.. I need fugu remote to do voice search, which it doesn't do without this.

Comment: Indeed, it is not released in AOSP, could be part of proprietary sources/libraries. (I will add this to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

That header file is not been used/included at all when build from AOSP with installing the binaries.

The REMOTE_CONTROL_INTERFACE would be defined if the device is fugu/fugu_gmscore_next at Android.mk:

[image]

But TARGET_PRODUCT value of the NexusPlayer/fugu is:

```
$ echo $TARGET_PRODUCT 
aosp_fugu
```

Besides, you can use the Audio Source which is generated by Remote Voice Control to do the recoginition by using the MediaRecorder with the source type to VOICE_RECOGNITION, according to the AudioPolicyManager codes.

**Whereas, when flashing the google binary image, I can certainly know that that macro is defined by checking the logcat and reverse-engining.**

Google just hide it...

Comment: Yes, I know header is conditionally included. I just wanted to know if header is also publicly available. Also, you misunderstand. I have a remote. I need voice search apps like Google/YT etc to work with my remote. I am not writing voice recognition app, so there is no opening MediaRecorder anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the same thing right now. And I updated my answer.